# Multiple buttons in a GUI / Add Key down Event Handler

Tags: powershell

I have already received valuable advice from another post and have already been able to expand "my little GUI project". I have built a GUI with different tabs and buttons based on a code (see screenshot 1)

[image: Screenshot]

If I trigger the underlying functions (search in a CSV, or ping from a target) via button, the whole thing works fine.

But I want to execute the actions when the user presses the enter key and here I have a problem. I'm trying to target the buttons with the following code:

*

```
Search by Site ID:
   $form.KeyPreview = $true
    $form.Add_Keydown({if ($_.Keycode -eq "Enter")
    {$button_Search.PerformClick()}})
```

- 

```
Ping command (under the Network tab): 
  $form.KeyPreview = $true
    $form.Add_Keydown({if ($_.Keycode -eq "Enter")
    {$button_Search_NW.PerformClick()}})
```

- 

I thought I can thus uniquely identify the buttons, but still both are addressed. If I search via Enter key for a site ID, I get the site ID, but at the same time I get the message in Powershell that the "SiteID" can't be reached via ping.

I hope I have expressed myself understandably. My question: How can I make it so that I can address the buttons clearly and with the Enter key also only the action is executed, in whose tab I am also currently moving.

Comment: Why not act on a button's Click() event? By using `$form.Add_Keydown`, a user can click anywhere in the form (or press enter) and then you need to figure out where, what button etc. I'd say do something like `$buttonNetwork.Add_Click({Show-NetworkTab})` and on the button inside that tab specify `$buttonPing.Add_Click({Start-Ping})` No confusion, each button will do what it is designed for and nothing more

Comment: Set `$form.AcceptButton = $searchButton` for instance. Then the search button reacts on `Return` key and you can handle it as Theo suggests.

Comment: I ran into the same problem with "AcceptButton". But again just needed some food for thought. I'm really embarrassed to ask a question here sometimes. But believe me, I sit there really hours on it (incl search in other forums), before I go to you on the nerves here. 

Anyway, the impetus from Theo was once again worth its weight in gold. Thank you very much!